# Exchange of limit and limsup for bounded and integrable function

Tags: real-analysis, limits, limsup-and-liminf

Let $g$ be an integrable function such that $g : \mathbb{R}^+ \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+$  and $g(x) < M$ for all $x$. Let $f_n: \mathbb{Z}^+ \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+$ such that 
$$f_n(x) = \sum_{i=0}^{x*n} \dfrac{g\left(\frac{i}{n}\right)}{x}.$$ If $f: \mathbb{Z}^+ \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+$ such that 
$$f(x) = \frac{\int_0^x g(t)dt}{x},$$ then $f_n$ is pointwisely convergent to f.

What I am trying to prove is 
\begin{equation} \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \limsup_{x \rightarrow \infty} f_n(x) = \limsup_{x \rightarrow \infty} \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f_n(x) = \limsup_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x).
\end{equation}

Since it is not uniformly convergent, I cannot not use Moore-Osgood Theorem. In order to obtain that, I try to use Weierstrass M Test but it is not applicable. Can somebody help me to prove this? Or can you give a counter example? 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I assumed you missed an $\frac{1}{n}$ in your definition of $f_n$. I guess it should be $$f_n(x) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=0}^{x*n} \dfrac{g\left(\frac{i}{n}\right)}{x}$$
Otherwise it would not hold $f_n \to f$ pointwise.

Comment: Additionally it's not clear what you mean with "an integrable function"?
Should $g$ be integrable on it's domain hence $$\int_0^\infty g(t) dt < +\infty$$ or only on any interval $[0,x]$?